# How to select subset of data from multiple columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Assume I have a table such as following and I would like to select customers who purchased more than 1 item.

| customer | item1 | item2 | item3 | item4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 5 | 11 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 7 | NULL | 9 | NULL |
| 4 | NULL | NULL | 2 | NULL |
| 5 | 7 | 13 | 9 | NULL |

My final output should be something like

| customer | item1 | item2 | item3 | item4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | 11 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 7 | NULL | 9 | NULL |
| 5 | 7 | 13 | 9 | NULL |

My code is

```
SELECT  
       customer
      ,item1
      ,item2
      ,item3
       item4
FROM StoreData
WHERE item1 IS NOT NULL OR 
      item2 IS NOT NULL OR
      item3 IS NOT NULL OR
      item4 IS NOT NULL
```

But this seems to be incorrect? Any suggestions? Many Thanks

Comment: what is incorrect is that the table structure is not normalized.  If possible begin by fixing that.  All your queries will become much more difficult than they need to be with your current structure.

Comment: This problem demonstrates the importance of a proper schema design. You can work around it but the resulting code is not so easy to understand. And good luck if you want to allow for 5 items. You can easily add a column to a table but you often cannot easily change code to accommodate the new schema.

Comment: Left unsaid: Your code checks to see if _any_ item is not `NULL`, but it doesn't check the _number_ of non-null items to determine if more than one is present. It is also unclear whether there can be more than one row per customer, e.g. what if somewhat purchased six items? What if there are multiple rows for a customer but all of the items are null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
WHERE 
(
 (CASE WHEN item1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
+(CASE WHEN item2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
+(CASE WHEN item3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
+(CASE WHEN item4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
) > 1
```

Comment: This exactly what I need. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT s.* 
from StoreData s 
inner join  (
               select customer,concat_ws('-',item1,item2,item3,item4) as orders
               from StoreData
             ) as t1 on t1.customer=s.customer
where CHARINDEX('-',orders ) >= 1;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3bb682bdde48bd3cb8939dd05858ddee)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this question is to use the "UNPIVOT" expression:

```
SELECT customer, COUNT(*) --, Item, Quantity
FROM dbo.StoreData
UNPIVOT  (
    Quantity FOR Item IN (item1, item2, item3, item4) 
) AS UnpivotTable
GROUP BY
    customer
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

The UNPIVOT command helps you to see item1, item2, ..., itemN as single rows.
Then you can apply a basic group by on it to check whether the count is greater the desired quantity or not.